# Experimental design: What gives you more statistical power: Increasing number of sub samples or replicates?

Tags: experiment-design, statistical-power

Say I have an experiment with a binary response: 0 or 1.

Within each experiment, I put X number of individuals in a group (X sub samples) and measure the proportion that has a response of 1 (e.g. 2/4). I replicate this with new groups of X individuals Z times. That is, Z number of replicates.

In order to increase statistical power the most (to detect differences in mean response/post hoc, maybe a ANOVA/Tukey HSD) would you increase the number of subsamples in each replicate, X, or increase the number of replicates (Z).

The answer is probably both, but does one have more contributing power than the other?

Comment: Do you know the within-group responses are independent?

Comment: Within group responses are not independent. I’m interested in how that would change things too.

Comment: It would help to know more about how and to what degree they are not independent.  Otherwise you might get good responses that aren't applicable to your situation.  Often in such situations there's a power-cost tradeoff, too, because it can be more efficient to create and observe groups compared to individuals.

Comment: Makes sense. The response of 1 individual does not necessarily cause the response of another within the same group. Nor does the lack of response cause the lack of response of others either. They are blocked by space, though. Besides that, they are independent I suppose.

Comment: However, when running stats, the proportion is calculated within each group. So there will be Z values for each type of ‘treatment’.

Comment: Does exp = 2/4 mean that the expected proportion is 1/2?

Comment: Sorry, exp means just as an example.

Comment: It's unclear what your "treatments" are: so far, you haven't mentioned any covariates apart from an indicator of "after" vs. "before."

Comment: Are you by any chance following survival of individuals ? Are groups something like individuals being kept together in a box ?

Comment: @CaroZ Exactly.

Comment: How many do you have in a group ?

Comment: Right now, 4. Continuing your answer, what if I reduced the group size to 1 and kept the same number if individuals? I would get a larger number of replicates , z … therefore increasing the power? That doesn’t make sense to me. There’s some balance here that I’m trying to better characterize.

Comment: Are you checking survival daily ? Or is it an endpoint measure ?

Comment: I understand that I could run like a Kaplan Meier analysis for an everyday mortality assessment. But I’m more interested in endpoint or just looking at one particular day.

Answer (score -2):

Your real sample is the group. It is good to have a sufficient number of individuals in each group so that your proportion does actually represent something of course, but better increase Z.

Edit after clarifications in the comments : I would consider individuals separately, each of them having one line in your dataset. I would have a "status" column with 0 being alive, 1 being dead.
Then, I would analyse the proportion of dead individuals with a GLMM for a binomial distribution, with the group as a random factor.

Comment: Can you substantiate this answer with some arguments, calculations, simulations, ... ?

Comment: One doesn't actually measure the proportion: the original data are the *counts.*  I would like to suggest that employing an appropriate model for the counts and analyzing it would lead to the opposite conclusion in many cases: $Z=1$ will yield the largest effective degrees of freedom because all results are independent.

Comment: @whuber This exactly describes the two schools of thought I had. But when running this data in a binomial model in this manner I often have challenges achieving statistical pair-wise separation between ‘levels’.  That is, the binary nature of Z=1 seems to have less power..?

Comment: @whuber I think we are in the same page. Do you mean treat the data as entirely binary?  Each replicate would be rather 0 or 1? Wouldn’t that make X=1?